# How do i allow user input to add to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Hey so I am trying to use this function along with a while loop with user input() to add to dictionary for example: user input = artist name, album name, and track number which gets stored inside a dictionary and once user input is done, to print the new dictionary from input data.

Along with a `if input == 'q' to quit.`

Thanks, sorry if my question isn't clear as this is my first question on SOF.

```
def make_album(artist_name, album_name, track_number):
    """Returns a dictionary of an Artist"""
    full_block = {'artist': artist_name, 'album': album_name, 'track': track_number}
    return full_block

musician = make_album('Jimi Hendrix', 'The experience', 23)
print(musician)
```

Comment: @program00, please let me know if my extended answer works

Comment: @Abhishek yes it works thank you !

Comment: you can upvote it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to come to a solution thanks to you :)

```
def make_album(artist_name, album_name, track_number):
""""Returns a dictionary of an Artist"""

artist_name = artist_name.strip()                   #removes the spaces
album_name = album_name.strip()                     #removes the spaces
track_number = track_number.strip()                 #removes the spaces

full_block = {'artist': artist_name, 'album': album_name, 'track': track_number}
return full_block


while True:     #I enter into the while loop
block_0 = input("Enter artist name: ")
if block_0 == 'q':
    print("quitting...")
    break

block_1 = input("Enter an album name: ")
if block_1 == 'q':
    print("quitting...")
    break

block_2 = input("Enter how many tracks: ")
if block_2 == 'q':
    print("quitting....")
    break

else:
    in_full = make_album(artist_name=block_0.title(), album_name=block_1.title(),    track_number=block_2.title())  
    print(in_full)
print("End...")
break
```

Comment: Good job, if you liked my answer, you can upvote it too

Answer (score 1):

Here!

```
def make_album(artist_name, album_name, track_number):
    """Returns a dictionary of an Artist"""

    artist_name = artist_name.strip() #Removes any spaces in the beginning or end
    album_name = album_name.strip() #Removes any spaces in the beginning or end
    track_number = track_number.strip() #Removes any spaces in the beginning or end


    full_block = {'artist': artist_name, 'album': album_name, 'track': track_number}
    return full_block

while True: #I enter into the while loop
    block = input("Enter artist, album, track seperated by comma")
    #Seperate artist, album, track by a COMMA. This is crucial
    if block == 'q':
        print("You pressed q, quitting...")
        break #I break out of the while loop if block which is the string variable that stores the input == 'q'

    else:
        album = block.split(",") #Split the string by comma into a list where each element will be the contents of the dictionary.
        musician = make_album(album[0], album[1], album[2])
        #Element in index 0 is artist_name
        #Element in index 1 is album_name
        #Element in index 2 is track_number
        print(musician)
```

If you want, seperate inputs for each of three details then:

```
def make_album(artist_name, album_name, track_number):
    """Returns a dictionary of an Artist"""

    artist_name = artist_name.strip()
    album_name = album_name.strip()
    track_number = track_number.strip()


    full_block = {'artist': artist_name, 'album': album_name, 'track': track_number}
    return full_block

while True:

    artist_name = input("Enter artist_name")
    album_name = input("Enter album_name")
    track_number = input("Enter album_name")

    if artist_name == 'q' or album_name == 'q' or track_number == 'q':
    #If even on of the inputs is q, it will break out of the while loop
        print("You pressed q, quitting..")
        break

    else:

        musician = make_album(artist_name, album_name, track_number)
        print(musician)
```

Comment: If you liked it, and it worked, upvote and accept! :) Good luck on your journey learning Python. It is the one of the BEST languages you've picked up.

Comment: How would i write for 3 separate inputs? artist name: Jimi Hendrix   Album name: Experience, Track Numbers: 22. Rather than having the input be separated by commas.

Comment: @progra00 There are 3 separate parameters being accepted by comma-seperated input. What may be confusing is that in Python, these are assigned the indices 0, 1, and 2; not 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: @progra00 Check the answer now! I've added an extended answer where there are THREE separate input statements.